# Validate an object instead of a value in Laravel

Tags: validation, eloquent, laravel-5

In my application I created a POST form which contains an ID of an Object.

When I post the form, I want to validate the object for a set of rules, like the age and model relationships of the object. I Created a custom ValidationTrait.

Instead of putting values in the $input, I would like to pass the entire Eloquent model. How can I do this ?

```
class AddParticipantToCourseFormRequest extends BaseRequest {
    public function getInput($includeFiles = false)
        {
            $participantId = Input::get('participant_id');
            $participant = Participant::find($participantId);
            $input[ 'participant' ] = $participant;
            return $input;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 5 you can create [Custom Validation Rules](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#custom-validation-rules). So you can define custom validation rule, let say `ValidObject` and assign it to your form request validation rules:

```
$rules = [
    .....
    'paritipant_id' => 'required|ValidObject',
];
```

To create a custom validation rule for `ValidObject` you can put this code in a new or existing service provider boot method:

```
Validator::extend('ValidObject', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    try {
        $participant = Participant::find($value);
        return $participant->your_check_here() = true;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

**Edit**

In case you want to replace some input value before the validation process, you can create a middleware and replace the input there.

```
php artisan make:middleware ReplaceParticipantMiddleware
```

Then go to your generated class and in the `handle` method replace the value

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
    try {
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['participant_id'] = Participant::find($input['participant_id']);
        $request->replace($input);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        // you error handling here
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Don't forget to add this middleware to the routes that will have this participant_id in routes.php

```
Route::get('/', [
     'middleware' => 'App\Http\Middleware\ReplaceParticipantMiddleware', 
     'uses' => 'WelcomeController@index'
]);
```

Now the routes that have this middleware will always have instance of Participant via `$request->input('particpant_id')` when they submit a particpant_id.

Comment: that is what I did, but I want to pass the participant to the validation function, because I need to test multiple rules. I want to avoid doing  $participant = Participant::find($value); multiple times.

Comment: @Nealv Ah now I understand what you want to achieve. See my edit.

Comment: Yes, this works, but the validation does not trigger on that field

Comment: I use a form request, and in my getInput() function I do: $input[ 'participant' ] = $participant; so the $input['participant'] contains the model object. in my rules is have   'participant'  => 'age:15'. but the validation rule does not get triggered when the input value is an object instead of a string (or other base objec tlike int, float ..)

Comment: never mind, for some odd reason, it didn't work, but now it does. thanks for the help.